# How to stack a dataset with two related variables in R

Tags: r, database, stack, dataset

I am pretty sure this question would be extraordinarily easy to solve for some navigating in this forum.

My problem is that my former dataset is structured as is shown below:

[image]

It represents XY coordinates in different samples (1, 2, 3, 4).

I would like to stack the data but keeping the relations between the coordinates, so that two variables (x and y) must be stacked. I'd like to get a result as this one shown here:

[image]

I am aware I can do it manually, but I am sure R would make my work more practical, optimizing my time. Obviously, this an example whose goal is to show the issue. My original data, which is not shown here, is composed by hundreds of columns and rows...

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a reproducible example of your dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
old <- data.frame(x1 = c(2.2, NA, NA, NA),
              y1 = c(2.1, NA, NA, NA), 
              x2 = c(2.3, 2.2, NA, NA), 
              y2 = c(2.5, 2.3, NA, NA),
              x3 = c(1.9, 2.1, 2.3, NA),
              y3 = c(2.6, 2.6, 2.3, NA),
              x4 = c(2.5, 2.6, 2.5, 2.1),
              y4 = c(2.1, 2.3, 2.6, 2.2))

new <- gather(old, xy, val) %>% 
    mutate(coord = substr(xy, 1, 1),
           pair = parse_number(xy)) %>% 
    group_by(xy) %>% 
    mutate(sample = 1:n()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-xy) %>% 
    spread(coord, val) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(x) & !is.na(y))

new
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    pair sample     x     y
   <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1      1   2.2   2.1
 2     2      1   2.3   2.5
 3     2      2   2.2   2.3
 4     3      1   1.9   2.6
 5     3      2   2.1   2.6
 6     3      3   2.3   2.3
 7     4      1   2.5   2.1
 8     4      2   2.6   2.3
 9     4      3   2.5   2.6
10     4      4   2.1   2.2
```

Note that the last line is only for removing missing data, and removes all rows that do not have valid entries on x and y. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks so much Daniel!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!